# Отмена выполнения функции

Tags: javascript

Как сделать условие, при котором при нажатии на кнопку 'Отмена' (alert) весь последующий алгоритм функции отменяется.

```
function calcEmpathyToGame(){
    const start = confirm('Определим насколько вы любите свою игру'),
        getName = prompt('Как называется ваша игра?'),
        getTime = prompt(`Сколько часов в ${getName} вы отыграли?`),
        getOtherGames = prompt('Сколько обычно часов в играх вы отыгрываете?');

    window.setTimeout((result) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Получение отправленных данных...');
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Данные получены...');
        }, 1500);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Обработка полученных данных...');
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Данные обработаны. Подготовка к операции.');
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Подождите, операция выполняется...');
        }, 3500);
        setTimeout(() => {
                result = (getTime > getOtherGames) 
                ? alert(`Вы очень любите играть в ${getName}, наиграв при этом целых ${getTime} часов!`) 
                : alert(`Вам не очень нравится играть в ${getName}. Вы наиграли только ${getTime} часов`) 
        }, 4000);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Можете показать код и показать визуально что вы хотите? А то пока не совсем ясно при чём тут алерт и отмена

Comment: "весь последующий алгоритм функции отменяется" - вот как надо формулировать! Я так не могу.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, обновил вопрос

Comment: О каком `alert` идёт речь? Вы в курсе, что у `alert` нет кнопки "Отмена"?

Comment: @wololo https://imgur.com/yaZRRSp , странно, у меня есть

Comment: Мои глаза сейчас лопнут.

Comment: @psheno это не alert)) Это диалоговое окно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо за замечание, учту

Comment: `confirm` возвращает `false`, если нажата "Отмена", иначе `true`. `prompt` возвращает `null`, если нажата "Отмена", иначе строку. Так и проверяйте. `if (start === false) return; ... if (getName === null) return; ...`

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать условие, при котором при нажатии на кнопку 'Отмена' (alert) весь последующий алгоритм функции отменяется.
> ну как и писали выше, вероятно речь про confirm. Остановить можно так

```
const start = confirm('Определим насколько вы любите свою игру');
if(!start) {return}
```

ну и чтобы в принципе фугкция запустилась, добавьте в конце calcEmpathyToGame();